# Define array from a bigger one in Fortran

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, fortran

I have a 4-dimensional array in Fortran called `covi` It is declared as:

```
real, dimension(10,10,2,2) :: covi
```

and computed in a certain way.

At some point, I need to take 2-dimensional slices of that array, lke for example `covi(1,1,:,:)`, `covi(3,4,:,:)`,`covi(7,5,:,:)`, etc.
I have declared another variable `real, dimension(2,2) :: cov` and written `cov=covi(7,5,:,:)` but this is not working. It gives the following error message:

```
error #6366: The shapes of the array expressions do not conform.   [COVI]
        covi = cov(i1,i2,:,:)
```

In Matlab this notation works perfectly. It is pretty intuitive. How does one achieve this in Fortran?

Thanks

Comment: `covi = cov(i1,i2,:,:)` doesn't match `cov=covi(7,5,:,:)`.

Comment: You just switched cov and covi by mistake...

Comment: side note, if you are frequently referencing those "2,2" "slices" it would be preferable to structure your 4d array as `(2,2,10,10)` as that makes the 4 values contiguous in memory.  Same applies to matlab.